# Looking for a mecha anime where a boy is crushed by a robot, but brought back to life?

Tags: story-identification, anime, mecha

I'm trying to recall the title of a series, but I have had no luck doing so thus far.

In the first episode, the protagonist is killed by a giant mecha landing on him, but its pilot somehow brings him back to life.
He is then forced(?) to attend an academy with other pilots who are protecting the country/planet? It's very much a parody series and does not take itself too seriously.

I have been searching mecha anime series as well before asking, but there are far too many generics. I believe I last saw this series maybe five years ago, around 2013-2014.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sounds like *Kurogane no Linebarrells* aka *[Linebarrels of Iron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linebarrels_of_Iron)*.

The protagonist Kouchi is killed when the eponymous mech Linebarrel falls on top of him out the sky, to paraphrase. I remember distinctly having watched this at the time.

A synopsis from Wikipedia reads as:

> His life is forever changed during a class trip in 2016 when an artificial satellite falls from orbit. Due to this "accident", Kouichi is left in a coma for half a year, and upon awakening, found himself with strange powers, including superhuman strength. Three years later, a mysterious robot called "Linebarrel" appears before him. It is revealed that the accident from three years ago was actually caused by the Machina robot Linebarrel and that this turned him into a "Factor", which is the name given to Machina pilots.

More specifically:

> Linebarrel's first Factor was Emi Kizaki however, became piloted by Kouichi Hayase after reviving him with its D-SOIL nano machines. Although Emi killed Kouichi, she begged Linebarrel to revive him.

Comment: I think this is it.